# cursor and text issue in the jquery UI autosuggest for CHROME

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am facing a weird issue with JQuery UI auto complete. What is happening is when I am trying to use the code located at JQUERY UI Autocomplete DEMOS

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple values</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
    function split( val ) {
        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
        return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#tags" )
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: function( request, response ) {
                // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                    availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                focusCampo(this.id);
                return false;
            }
        });
});

function focusCampo(id) {
    var inputField = document.getElementById(id);
    if (inputField != null && inputField.value.length != 0) {
        if (inputField.createTextRange) {
            var FieldRange = inputField.createTextRange();
            FieldRange.moveStart('character', inputField.value.length);
            FieldRange.collapse();
            FieldRange.select();
        } else if (inputField.selectionStart || inputField.selectionStart == '0') {
            var elemLen = inputField.value.length;
            inputField.selectionStart = elemLen;
            inputField.selectionEnd = elemLen;
            inputField.focus();
        }
    } else {
        inputField.focus();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>
<input id="tags" size="50" />
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

With additional Script I got from Stackoverflow.. I don't recollect exact link. I am able to solve my cursor and text alignment issue. But on Chrome it doesn't work! On chrome it looks like 
[This is how It looks on CHROME http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/7144/uiissues.png](http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/7144/uiissues.png)
Please can anybody help me out in finding problem in this code?? The code is working fine for rest of browsers. Please try the code.. It's completely written. Just copy-paste it and run. It works fine in IE9,FF. 
Exact Issue is the cursor position is different but Textbox contents are not shown properly in chrome .. i.e. it's not moving ahead where the cursor actually lies. Please try it out and let me know. sorry for poor English.. can't explain problem properly .. Lack of vocabulary !

Comment: Just copy pasted your code into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/59YaL/1/) Can you explain whats behaving differently in Chrome in comparison with browsers like Firefox? Tested it in Chrome and Firefox and it behaves the same

Comment: Nah see it neatly.  When the length of text increases than the size of textbox then in the chrome when you add new element from auto suggest the partial text is visible and rest of the text is visible if you press arrow key or type something that's what I was trying to show in that image. Try selecting 5 to 6 actionscript one after another you will experience what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

In your focusCampo function, add the following 2 lines after the else if statement should fix the problem with Chrome.

```
inputField.blur();
inputField.focus();
```